# Why does the implementation of lazy loading in C# not work properly?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, lazy-loading

I am developing a wpf app (.net framework) and I want to implement lazy loading for a listview. So when a button is clicked, I get the data piece by piece from the database and add it to the listview until the listview vertical scrollbar appears. The problem is that the first time I click on the button, all the data from the database is added to the listview. But from the second time on, my code runs correctly, that is, the data from the database is added to the listview only until the scrollbar appears. Can someone explain why this happens and what is the solution?

This is the code I wrote:

Note: I bind listView ItemsSource property to a BindingList named PeopleList.

```cs
private void DisplayAllPeople()
{
    _peopleTablePageNumber = 0;
    PeopleList = new BindingList<Person>();

    bool isScrollBarVisible = false;
    bool isEndOfTable = false;
    while (!isScrollBarVisible && !isEndOfTable)
    {
        IEnumerable<Person> peoplePage = _dataCollector.GetPersons()
            .Skip(_peopleTablePageNumber * _peoplePerPageCount)
            .Take(_peoplePerPageCount);

        PeopleList.AddRange(peoplePage);

        _peopleTablePageNumber++;

        ScrollViewer sv = FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(listViewPeople);
        Visibility VerticalScrollbarVisibility = sv.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility;
        isScrollBarVisible = (VerticalScrollbarVisibility == Visibility.Visible);

        isEndOfTable = (peoplePage.Count() < _peoplePerPageCount);
    }
}

private childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj) 
    where childItem : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (child != null && child is childItem)
            return (childItem)child;
        else
        {
            childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child);
            if (childOfChild != null)
                return childOfChild;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

UPDATE:
This is the GetPersons method of my DataCollector class:

```cs
public List<Person> GetPersons()
{
    return _dBContext.Persons.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Please provide the implementation of `_dataCollector.GetPersons()`.

Comment: I updated the question and added the `GetPerons()` method.

Comment: Do you understand that you are loading all data from database into memory by calling it ToList()?!

Comment: Well, that GetPersons() method loads everything into the list -> no longer lazy. But the problem may be elsewhere.

Comment: I will solve that problem later, but for now the problem is somewhere else. @PaulPalmpje

Comment: The only possible answer is that the scrollbar doesn't become visible on the the first run. Have you tried outputting some debug information from the loop? I find this reference to the view from the viewmodel a little disturbing. There must be some way to do it in XAML.

Comment: Yes, I traced the code and the main problem is that in the first run, the ScrollBar doesn't become visible. @PalleDue

Comment: What is the value of _peoplePerPageCount?

Comment: It is 40. @emoacht

Comment: You execute peoplePage IEnumerable iterations twice at `PeopleList.AddRange(peoplePage)` and `peoplePage.Count()`. Is it guaranteed that _dBContext provides the same elements?

Comment: Have you considered calculating the expected number of rows that'll fit in advance? I'd prefer that way myself to checking whether a scroll viewer needs to scroll stuff. If you make that async and stick await task delay in after each read, does it work first time?

Comment: I would strongly advise an observable collection and item viewmodel over binding list. No idea if they fixed it but there were long standing bugs in Wpf associated with binding list.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use that lazy loading? If it is only for performance you might want to look into WPF Virtualisation, which does not load all elements into the listview at once.

But be careful if you put your element into an scrollviewer virtualisation does not work because inside the scrollviewer there will always be enaugh space to load all elements.